# Python memory use in loop function call vs variable assigment

Tags: python, performance, loops

Lets say I have a dataframe which I want to transform into list of dictionaries and loop over them.

What would be more efficient?

```
df = some_dataframe
df_as_list = df.to_dict('records')

for i in df_as_list:
    requests.get(i['url'])
```

or

```
df = some_dataframe
for i in df.to_dict('records'):
    requests.get(i['url'])
```

Does the second example call to_dict() on every loop?

Comment: Did you try testing/profiling them?

Comment: No, they're equivalent. `for i in` loops over the result of calling `df.to_dict`

Comment: try evaluating the execution time of each one with a significant amount of data, but no i dont think it is called each time in the second code.

Comment: @mrCopiCat what would it mean to evaluate it each time? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: evaluating the execution time of the whole code not i didn't say to 'evaluate it each time'

Comment: No, it's called once. `df.to_dict` is called once to get an iterable, then the `for` loop calls `iter` on that to get an iterator, then the iterator's `__next__` method is called repeatedly, the same as in the first example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one call to `to_dict`. The `for` loop is basically equivalent to

```
t = iter(df.to_dict('records'))
while True:
    try:
        i = next(t)
    except StopIteration:
        break

    requests.get(i['url'])
```

It doesn't matter whether you assign the result of `df.to_dict` to a variable or not, because the *result* is simply passed to `iter`, and that iterable is passed to `next` multiple times.